# Put an array in a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Assume that I have a function that generates an $m \times n$ array of numbers and I want to put this array in a specified place in an $(m+n) \times (m+n)$ matrix. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to overwrite an $m\times n$ block in a matrix with a different (smaller) matrix?

Comment: First, I have a zero $(m+n) \times (m+n)$ matrix and I want to put the array in the up-right $m \times n$ block in the matrix.

Answer (score 6):

You can index into matrices directly using `Part` or its shortcut `[[ ]]`. For example, to place the random 2-by-3 matrix `n` in the upper right of the larger 4-by-5 matrix `m`:

```
m = ConstantArray[0, {4, 5}];
n = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {2, 3}];
m[[1 ;; 2, 3 ;; 5]] = n
m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

The indexing into `m` is (in this example) rows 1 to 2, and columns 3 to 5.
The assignment will work as long as this matches the number of rows and columns in `n`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `PadLeft` or `PadRight`

```
mat := {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}}
PadLeft[#, {-#, #} &[Total[Dimensions[#]]]] &[mat] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

To specify the place you need `ArrayPad`

```
With[{x = 1, y = 3, dim = Dimensions[#]},
  ArrayPad[#, {{y, # - y}, {x, #2 - x}} & @@
    (Total[dim] - dim)]] &[mat] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 \\
>  0 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

> *I want to put the array in the up-right m×n block in the matrix.*

```
padF[m_] := Normal[SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1 + Dimensions[m][[1]]] -> m},
  Total[Dimensions[m]] {1, 1}]]

mat = Partition[Range@8, 4];
padF[mat] // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**Original answer:**

You can use [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SparseArray.html) and  [`Band`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Band.html):

```
padF[pos_, m_] := Normal[Quiet@SparseArray[{Band[pos] -> m}, Total[Dimensions[m]] {1, 1}]]
```

Examples:

```
mat = Partition[Range@8, 4];
padF[{1, 3}, mat] // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
padF[{2, 3}, mat] // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
padF[{3, 4}, mat] // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$